# QueryDSL Date arithmetic

Tags: java, jpa, querydsl

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sma`.`MIGRation` (
`MIGR_ID` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`MIGR_From` VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL ,
`MIGR_To` VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL ,
`MIGR_Validity_Days` INT NOT NULL ,
`MIGR_CreationDate` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`MIGR_ID`) );
```

How would you write an expression in QueryDSL to find the entries which are still valid (creationDate + validity_Days)?

```
SELECT * FROM MIGRation WHERE DATE_ADD(MIGR_CreationDate, INTERVAL MIGR_Validity_Days DAY) > now()
```

Answer (score 8):

For arithmetic queries take a look at the `com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.Expressions` class. In this case it is possible to use `Expressions::dateTimeOperation`:

```java
import com.querydsl.core.types.Ops;
import com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.*;
import com.querydsl.sql.SQLQuery;
...
    @Transactional
    public List<MIGRationEntity> getMigration() {
        SQLQuery<MIGRationEntity> query = selectFrom(QMIGRation.MIGRation)
            .where(
                Expressions.dateTimeOperation(
                    Date.class, Ops.DateTimeOps.ADD_DAYS,
                    QMIGRation.MIGRation.mIGRCreationDate,
                    QMIGRation.MIGRation.mIGRValidityDays)
                .gt(DateTimeExpression.currentTimestamp()));
        String sql = query.getSQL().getSQL();
        System.out.print(sql);
        return query.fetch();
    }
...
```

The created SQL:

```sql
select MIGRation.MIGR_CreationDate, MIGRation.MIGR_From, MIGRation.MIGR_ID, MIGRation.MIGR_To, MIGRation.MIGR_Validity_Days
from MIGRation MIGRation
where date_add(MIGRation.MIGR_CreationDate, interval MIGRation.MIGR_Validity_Days day) > current_timestamp
```

Comment: I am using this exact code, but I don't get the `date_add` function in the resultant query. Rather, it has  function `schema_name.add_minutes` and it fails, since there is no such function.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and I have solved it in the following way. The idea is to compare two dates from different entities to which a day is added to a previous date.

.or(cese.fcServBaja.isNotNull().and(Expressions.dateTemplate(LocalDate.class, "{0} + 1", cese.fcServBaja).eq(ptDiasPermiso.compId.fcInicio)))

**Expressions.dateTemplate(LocalDate.class, "{0} + 1", cese.fcServBaja)** indicates the type of data I want, the second is the expression in SQL where the {0} is the field that is replaced by the parameter cese. fcServBaja.

As I understand it, the template contains the native database operation (I use Oracle)

I hope it helps you.